# popup with PartialView edit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, devexpress

I want to display a popup with a PartialView when I click on edit button on javascript. my problem how to pass an id value in @ Html.Action ("Edit", "Equipment", new {id = ????})

I am using a DevExpress gridview, and when I select a row and I click on button edit, a popup appears with information

my code :

```
<button type="button" class="md-trigger btn btn-success" id="Modif">Modifier</button>
div class="renderaction modal fade bs-example-modal-lg"  tabindex="-1" id="ModifEquipement" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   @Html.Action("Edit", "Equipement", new { id = ??? });
</div>
```

and in javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Modif").on("click", function () {                       
       $("#ModifEquipement").modal();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? I see that you pass the `Model.Id`

Comment: I'm using DevExpress gridview and when I select a row and I click on edit button a popup displays with all information

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 4 you can link from one view to another controller passing the Id or Primary Key via

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Equipement", new { id=item.equpementid}, null)
```

Comment: but Model.equpementid return 0